# T SQL, Get new customer added or deleted from historical table

Tags: sql-server-2016, change-data-capture, self-join

I have a Table containing historical data. Every day the same staff list will be added with the new dates (between 1200-12500 staff each day however only a few staff might be newly added todaysDate or they may have left the company yesterday and not showing on todays list).

I want to know each day which staff wasn't on yesterday list, it is new staff and the staff was showing yesterday but not today because they left company. I have tried the following but no joy please help
my historical table is like below and I need a script to get the rows for ID4 and ID5 only.

| StaffID | StaffName | CensusDate |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ID1 | Staff1 | 02/03/2021 |  |
| ID1 | Staff1 | 03/03/2021 |  |
| ID2 | Staff2 | 02/03/2021 |  |
| ID2 | Staff2 | 03/03/2021 |  |
| ID3 | Staff3 | 02/03/2021 |  |
| ID3 | Staff3 | 03/03/2021 |  |
| ID4 | Staff4 | 02/03/2021 | not showing today |
| ID5 | Staff5 | 03/03/2021 | is newly added today |
| ID6 | Staff6 | 02/03/2021 |  |
| ID6 | Staff6 | 03/03/2021 |  |
| ID7 | Staff7 | 02/03/2021 |  |
| ID7 | Staff7 | 03/03/2021 |  |

```sql
SELECT StaffID, StaffNAME, CensusDate
FROM table1 AS A 
LEFT JOIN table1 AS B 

ON A.StaffID = B.StaffID AND A.date = GETDATE())  AS date) 
and B.date = CAST(DATEADD(day, -1, convert(date, GETDATE())) AS date) 
AND A.staffID IS NULL
```

Comment: Could you please provide your table definitions?

Comment: Thanks for checking my post.is this what you mean: [StafName] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
[CensusDate] [date] NULL,
[StaffID] [float] NULL,

Comment: this is my scrip that  i need help with SELECT StaffID, StaffNAME, CensusDate FROM table1 as a Left join table2 as b ON a.StaffID=b.StaffID and a.date= GETDATE()) AS date) and b.date = CAST(DATEADD(day, -1, convert(date, GETDATE())) AS date) AND A.staffID IS NULL

Comment: Yes can you please post your table definitions in your question post? Your query uses two different tables `Table1` and `Table2`. Or are they the same table and you were just trying to indicate two different instances of the same table?

Comment: it is one historical table not two and the following script almost right just need to validate the data Many Thanks for your help so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's likely a simpler way, but I think this achieves what you're looking for:

```
WITH CTE_TodaysStaff AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT T1.StaffID
    FROM table1 AS T1
    WHERE T1.CensusDate = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
),
CTE_NotShowingToday AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT T1.StaffID
    FROM table1 AS T1
    LEFT JOIN CTE_TodaysStaff AS T2
         ON T1.StaffID = T2.StaffID
    WHERE T1.CensusDate = CAST(DATEADD(DAY, -1, GETDATE()) AS DATE)
        AND T2.StaffID IS NULL
 ),
CTE_NewToday AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT T1.StaffID
    FROM CTE_TodaysStaff AS T1
    LEFT JOIN table1 AS T2
        ON T1.StaffID = T2.StaffID
        AND T2.CensusDate < CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
    WHERE T2.StaffID IS NULL
 )

 SELECT T1.StaffID, T1.StaffNAME, T1.CensusDate, 
     CAST(CASE WHEN T2.StaffID IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS BIT) AS IsNotShowingToday,
     CAST(CASE WHEN T3.StaffID IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS BIT) AS IsNewToday
FROM table1 AS T1
LEFT JOIN CTE_NotShowingToday AS T2
    ON T1.StaffID = T2.StaffID
LEFT JOIN CTE_NewToday AS T3
    ON T1.StaffID = T3.StaffID
```

Comment: the script is giving me (Error converting data type nvarchar to float) StaffID is float in my table.

Comment: @Nick I don't see any reason why you'd be getting that data type error, weird. Can you find out which line is throwing that error? (Try running each CTE query individually if you need to. The second and third CTE are dependent on the first one, so you'll need to run those together.)

Comment: J.D. you are right it is working perfectly now it was my mistake with some changes. Great job. Thank youuuuuuuuuu

Comment: @Nick Great, no problem!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I completely understand your intention or the difference between Table1 and Table2.
If you are trying to find just the IDs that only occur once in the last two days.

```
SELECT StaffID, count(StaffID)
FROM Table1 
WHERE CensusDate >= cast(dateadd(day, -2, getdate()) as date)
Group By StaffID
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but the J.D. script is correct for what I am looking for.